# Sample video chat from Quickblox not working in Android

Tags: android, quickblox

I cannot run any sample application in Quickblox Android samples. It shows me `NoClassDefinitionFoundException in SmackAndroid.init(this);`.

I attached Quickblox jar to the build path and also done checking it in Order and Export. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the application. But it still shows me the same exception. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Update ADT plugin to the latest version

Comment: I am already Using the Latest Version of ADT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

`NoClassDefinitionFoundException in SmackAndroid.init(this);` is due to eclipse(juno) not importing the library properly. I tried using Intellij Idea, Eclipse Luna then Quickblox working fine. Now I able to use the quickblox functions cheers. Hope, this will help some one.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the jar given by quickblox

right click on the project, properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export
and put a checkmark on the Quickblox jar

Comment: Thanx for the info, I found the solution.